# Как можно показать сколько миллисекунд прошло? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне на WPF надо сделать игру "успел - не успел", игрок должен успеть нажать на кнопку и программа выведет ему за сколько миллисекунд он нажал на кнопку.
Как я могу запустить таймер когда игра начнётся, остановить его после нажатия и вывести сколько миллисекунд прошло?

Comment: [Stopwatch](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch), либо просто запомните дату старта и после окончания высчитывайте разницу.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ как решение, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

```
  //Создаём объект класса Stopwatch
  var stopwatch= new Stopwatch();

  //Запускаем отсчёт времени
  stopwatch.Start();

  //По нажатию кнопки останавливаем
  stopwatch.Stop();

  //Извлекаем полученное время
  var time = stopwatch.Elapsed;

  var result = "Время: " + time.ToString(@"m\:ss\.fff");
```

Comment: таймер и секундомер - 2 большие разницы, вводя слово `timer` там, где его нет, вы путаете тех, кто читает ваш код.

Comment: @aepot это общепринятая практика, ни разу не видел, чтобы кто-то писал секундомер. На всякий случай поправил, не хочется в минус) Википедия тоже за первоначальный вариант: Таймер (от англ. Timer) — в информатике средство обеспечения задержек и измерения времени средствами компьютера.

Comment: `sw` `stopwatch`. Дело не в словах, а в том что класс `Timer` тоже существует и выполняет он совершенно другие задачи.

Comment: @aepot ок, спасибо за аргумент, учту